# Configure Visual Studio Autocomplete to list classes outside of namespace?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

When I type in the autocomplete/intellisense for Visual Studio, if the thing I'm trying to reference isn't part of the current namespace, it won't show it at all.

Is there a way to get the Visual Studio autocomplete to include the names of classes that are in my solution, but not necessarily in my current namespace?  This would be similar to how the autocomplete for Typescript works in VS Code - it lists things that match what you type, then automatically imports them upon completion.

IntelliJ autocomplete for Java also works the way I'd like it to - when I start typing, it gives me a list of all the various things that match, including their classpath, so I can pick the one I need.

If this is a thing for Visual Studio, I can't figure out how to configure it to do this.

Comment: Are there references to the other project in the one you're currently working on?

Comment: Generally, yes. But not necessarily.

Comment: I added an answer, I think that might be your issue.

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper you will do the job (expensive but powerful). 
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Coding_Assistance_Code_Completion_Auto.html

If you need just to extend VS intellisense you can try this one:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dreamescaper.IntellisenseExtender2019

Answer (score 1):

With Visual Studio 2019 now there is an IntelliSense option to "Show items from unimported namespaces" to achieve similar functionality to ReSharper. You still need to have added a reference to the project though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is due to a lack of a reference from one project to the other. In the project you're working on, you have to manually add a reference to the project you're trying to reach.

Right-click the project node in Solution Explorer > Add > Reference > Projects > (your project name)

Then in the code, you probably want to include a using statement to reference the namespace and classes. Something along the lines of: `using YourNamespace;` `using YourNamespace.YourClass;` and so on depending on your needs.

But with the reference added, VS should be able to find the namespaces (similar to adding an external library).

The thing to keep in mind is that IntelliJ, and the autocomplete features in VS Code work much differently than Intellisense for C#. The former basically just looks through the code for similar usages, and infers from that that it's a potential member/function of what you're referencing. You'll see this in regular text editors like Atom and whatever. Autocomplete for C# is much more involved and VS does a lot more with reading the actual code and is less about inferring. I'm guessing this was done because it's easier for them to implement just based on the nature of the languages.

Comment: This isn't really desirable. If you read my question, I'm specifically trying to avoid having to manually reference/import the item -- mostly because I have no clue where it is half of the time, and it's a distraction to go find it.

Comment: IntelliJ autocomplete for Java works the way I'm looking for VS to work.

Comment: I think you're going to find it pretty difficult to reference other projects without an explicit reference. I can add more info, but IntelliJ and other autocomplete features work much differently than Intellisense for C#.